# Wix: How to add browse button in Wix

Tags: wix

Is there a simple way to add browse button in Wix. I created a custom by modifying from WixUI_InstallDir.wxs. This browse button is in another dialog (not the same one as for locating the installation path). This browse button will be use to specify the path to put my log files that will be created during installation.

**EDIT:**

sorry about the confusion on "below code". I intended to show the codes initially but the space on the above reply was limited. Here I've added the codes. I manage to show the Browse dialog now but i need to be able to change the path so that it is not same as the Browse dialog path of the installation path which is _BrowseProperty. My code below is using _LogBrowseProperty but i'm not sure how do i properly define it and at where should i define it. Using the code below will generate 2819 error. Can you help to take a look on what is wrong here? Thanks a lot.

CUSTOMDIR is defined in Product.wxs

```
 <Property Id='CUSTOMDIR' Value="TARGETDIR"></Property>
```

Below is in MyWixUI_InstallDir.wxs

```
   <Control Id="LogFolderLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="160" Width="290" Height="30" NoPrefix="yes"
                     Text="Folder Label" />
            <Control Id="LogFolder" Type="PathEdit" X="20" Y="200" Width="320" Height="18" Property="CUSTOMDIR"
                     Indirect="yes" />
            <Control Id="ChangeFolder" Type="PushButton" X="20" Y="220" Width="56" Height="17"
                     Text="Change Folder" />
```

....

```
  <Publish Dialog="myDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_LogBrowseProperty" Value="[CUSTOMDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="myDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>


  <Property Id="_LogBrowseProperty" Value="TARGETDIR" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a while at trying to do the same thing and amended the Wix BroseDlg dialog to achieve this.

In the parent control I had the following path edit and push button controls:

```
<Control Id="LogFilePathValue" Type="PathEdit" X="50" Y="205" Width="215" Height="18" Property="LOGFILE_PATH"/>
    <Control Id="LogFilePathButton" Type="PushButton" X="270" Y="205" Width="50" Height="17" Text="!(loc.LogFilePathButton_Text)">
      <Publish Property="LOGFILE_PATH_TEMP" Value="[LOGFILE_PATH]" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="MyLogFileDialog" Order="2">1</Publish>
    </Control>
</Control>
```

MyLogFileDialog then looked like this:

```
<Dialog Id="MyLogFileDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.MyLogFileDialog_DialogTitle)">
    <Control Id="PathEdit" Type="PathEdit" X="25" Y="202" Width="320" Height="18" Property="LOGFILE_PATH_TEMP" />
    <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="240" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIOK)">
      <Publish Property="LOGFILE_PATH" Value="[LOGFILE_PATH_TEMP]" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="2">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="ComboLabel" Type="Text" X="25" Y="58" Width="44" Height="10" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgComboLabel)" />
    <Control Id="DirectoryCombo" Type="DirectoryCombo" X="70" Y="55" Width="220" Height="80" Property="LOGFILE_PATH_TEMP" Fixed="yes" Remote="yes">
      <Subscribe Event="IgnoreChange" Attribute="IgnoreChange" />
    </Control>
    <Control Id="WixUI_Bmp_Up" Type="PushButton" X="298" Y="55" Width="19" Height="19" ToolTip="!(loc.BrowseDlgWixUI_Bmp_UpTooltip)" Icon="yes" FixedSize="yes" IconSize="16" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgWixUI_Bmp_Up)">
      <Publish Event="DirectoryListUp" Value="0">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="NewFolder" Type="PushButton" X="325" Y="55" Width="19" Height="19" ToolTip="!(loc.BrowseDlgNewFolderTooltip)" Icon="yes" FixedSize="yes" IconSize="16" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgNewFolder)">
      <Publish Event="DirectoryListNew" Value="0">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="DirectoryList" Type="DirectoryList" X="25" Y="83" Width="320" Height="98" Property="LOGFILE_PATH_TEMP" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no" />
    <Control Id="PathLabel" Type="Text" X="25" Y="190" Width="320" Height="10" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgPathLabel)" />
    <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgBannerBitmap)" />
    <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.MyLogFileDialog_TitleBody)" />
    <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.MyLogFileDialog_TitleMain)" />
  </Dialog>
```

You then have to make sure the property LOGFILE_PATH is set prior to calling this parent form.  In my case I'm using my own version of the UI_Mondo so I set the property after the user has selected the install type:

```
  <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="TypicalButton" Property="LOGFILE_PATH" Value="[COMPONENTINSTALLFOLDER]\Logs" Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="TypicalButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="ParentDialogWithLogLocationControls" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to examine the WiXUIExtension closer, especially the WixUI_InstallDir.wxs and InstallDirDlg.wxs. See how the controls and dialogs are set up in order to handle directory browsing properly and try to adjust it to your needs.

From InstallDirDlg.wxs:

```
<Control Id="Folder" Type="PathEdit" X="20" Y="100" Width="320" Height="18" Property="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Indirect="yes" />
<Control Id="ChangeFolder" Type="PushButton" X="20" Y="120" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgChange)" />
```

From WixUI_InstallDir.wxs:

```
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
...
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

Comment: i try to add the below code within my dialog that has the browse button. But i still can't make it work. There is error code 2343. Can you give more tips on what should i look out for. Really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are 2 _BrowseProperty, one for the installtion path and the other is for the new browse button. How should i add this(
          <Property Id="BrowseProperty2" Value="c:\MyExistingFolder" />) . I can't reuse the same Property and Value taf in n Publish tag because it can't be same with the install location. May i know what is the correct way to make it work?

Comment: It's very hard to understand the problem by your description. The "below code" is a vague term. The error code description can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835.aspx. I suggest you to do the following: create a clean WiX project, add UIExtension and make it work by default. Afterwards, add your custom dialog you'd like to add "browse" functionality to and try to make it work following the example of InstallDirDialog, not literally copying/pasting the code. When you make this simple example work, it would be easier to include the logic to your real installer.